# HackRF - Gqrx - Mac - No Sound

Tags: macos

Hello I have installed Gqrx on my mac following the tutorial here (to use with my HackRF):
http://k1fm.us/2014/08/i-finally-got-my-hackrf-and-i-have-a-mac-now-what/

Everything loads as it should but there is no sound. I have tried all the Audio options but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://www.smittix.co.uk/installing-the-latest-version-of-gqrx-on-macos-el-capitan/) make sure you've selected a `Mode` other than `Demod Off` in the View->`Receiver Options`(Shortcut:<kbd>⌘R</kbd>) - e.g. like `AM`.

But sometimes the config files can get messed up so it still doesn't work in which case you can try to reset the config file from the terminal:

```
/Applications/Gqrx.app/Contents/MacOS/gqrx -r
```

Comment: this did also reset the squelch setting which was the actual issue for me - all sound was squelched away.